# How to add product custom options in cart

Tags: cart, custom-options

I need add in cart for my products also and custom options, I need  display not only total price but also custom options value with price.

Thanks

Comment: Sergey,Are you want to Programmatically cart custom option product

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838558/how-to-programmatically-add-a-product-with-custom-options-to-cart-in-magento

Comment: I need how this: http://prntscr.com/47up0l , test_1 and test_2 this custom options, i need price display also with custom options in cart, can?

Comment: sergy.. you want to custom option price ??  it not clear in picture... please explain

Comment: Yes i want custom options price display in cart, so where indicated by the arrow in the screenshot, there must be a price

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In default.phtml file at  `app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtemplate/template/checkout/cart/item`
add the below code

```
 <?php if ($_options = $this->getOptionList()):?>

    <?php $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProduct()->getId()); ?>

    <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
    <?php $_formatedOptionValue = $this->getFormatedOptionValue($_option) ?>
    <?php foreach ($product->getProductOptionsCollection() as $option) { ?>

    <?php if($option->getTitle()==$_option['label']):?>             
    <strong><?php //echo $this->htmlEscape($_option['label']) ?></strong>
    <?php //echo $_formatedOptionValue['value'] ?>
    <br/>
        <!-- -->
            <?php
              switch ($option->getGroupByType()) {
                          case Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_GROUP_SELECT:

                foreach ($option->getValuesCollection() as $value) {
                    if($value->getTitle()==$_formatedOptionValue['value']){
                    echo "<br/>";
                   /*   echo '|value_id =>'. $value->getId();
                       echo '|title=>'.$value->getTitle();
                       echo '|price=>'. $value->getPrice();
                        echo '|price_type=>'. $value->getPriceType();
                       echo '|sku=>'. $value->getSku();
                       echo '|sort_order =>'. $value->getSortOrder();
                       */
                       if($value->getPriceType()=='fixed' && !is_null($value->getPrice())):
                       echo $value->getPrice()*$this->getQty();
                       endif;

                       if($value->getPriceType()=='percent' && !is_null($value->getPrice())):
                       echo $value->getPrice()*$this->getQty()*$Yourutemprice;
                       endif;



                    }
                }
                break;
                default:

                       if($option->getPriceType()=='fixed' && !is_null($option->getPrice())):
                       echo $option->getPrice()*$this->getQty();
                       endif;

                       if($option->getPriceType()=='percent' && !is_null($option->getPrice())):
                       echo $option->getPrice()*$this->getQty()*$Yourutemprice;
                       endif;



              }
              ?>      
            <!-- -->
        <?php endif; ?>        
     <?php } ?> 


    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Amit, but i have question: possible display price custom options in Unit price and Subtotal column? If custom options my checkout will have several options (my checkout 1 and my checkout 2), how will be work? And Yourutemprice what this? Thanks

Comment: yes.you can display on unit price columns.Also my code have checked multiple Options.

Comment: If you have time can you explain?

Comment: i am busy..let you khow

Comment: Amit you have time help me?